# Python Element-wise Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

In MATLAB, I do a calculation using

```
repmat(A-B,100,1).*rand(100,length(B))
```

Here, `A` and `B` are 1*19-sized matrices.

To execute the same code in Python, I am using the following code-

```
np.matmul(np.matlib.repmat(A - B, 100, 1), np.matlib.rand(100, len(B)))
```

Upon running the code, I get the following error-

```
ValueError: matmul: 
  Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, 
  with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) 
  (size 100 is different from 19)
```

What should I do?

Comment: What numpy version are you using? I can't find `np.matlib` in 1.22.0 for instance. Providing A and B vectors would also be helpful.

Comment: np.matmul implements matrix matrix mulitiplication. This requires the matrices to have matching dimnsions, (x,k), (k,y). For elementwise multiplication you can do A*B

Comment: I just check the docs and this has been deprecated since 1.19.0. It is worth to have a look at the pointed docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html).

Comment: I've answered a number of `repmat` related SO over the years.  It can be replaced by `np.repeat`, `np.tile` or `broadcasting.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a901925%20repmat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB's `.*` is a [broadcasting operator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). It scalar-extends the `*` operator to apply to matrices of matching size *pointwise*. This is *not* [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), which is a different operation available on matrices that requires the middle two dimensions to match.

The equivalent of `.*` in Python, assuming the left-hand and right-hand side are `numpy` arrays, is simply `*`.

```
np.matlib.repmat(A - B, 100, 1) * np.matlib.rand(100, len(B))
```

If the left-hand and right-hand side are *not* `numpy` arrays (for instance, if they're ordinary Python lists), then you can convert them by calling [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) on them beforehand